# Layer with point not appearing on map OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, cookies, openlayers

I am using cookies to save location data from points, the cookies save latitude and longitudes.

Then I try to re-draw the points based on the saved latitude and longitudes, but nothing appears on the map.

I have tried adding the layer after the map is created and nothing happens. I have switched the order of the layers. When I remove the fromLonLat function for some reason it draws a whole map underneath the original map (but with no points). Not sure what is going on here.

```
//look for previously saved points
let hpt = new Cookie("draw_point");
var coordinates_poly;
var vector_source;
var vector_layer;
if (hpt.lat && hpt.long) {
 
 //draw the point based on coordinates
 coordinates_poly = [parseFloat(hpt.long), parseFloat(hpt.lat)];
 console.log(coordinates_poly)
 features_to_draw.push(new Feature({
   geometry: new Point(olProj.fromLonLat(coordinates_poly, 'EPSG:3857'))
 }));

 vector_source = new VectorSource({
   features: features_to_draw,
   wrapX: false,
 });

 vector_layer = new VectorLayer({
   source: vector_source,
   style: new Style({
     image: new Circle({
       radius: 2,
       fill: new Fill({color: 'red'}),
       stroke: new Stroke({color: '#bada55', width: 1}),
     })
   })
 });
 
}

const map = new Map({
  layers: [raster, vector, vector_layer],
  target: 'map',
  view: view,

});
```

Comment: `coordinates_poly` is already an array, so you do not need `[ ]` around `coordinates_poly` in `fromLonLat()`

Comment: Thank you, it however it still does not work